# Select row by column id AND include rows that contain the same value from another column if null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a row by ID but also include rows that have the same value in other column but not including them if the value is `null` or empty.

Data:

```
+------+------+------+
|ID     GROUP |AREA  |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 2    |      | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 3    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 4    | B    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 5    |      | BB   |
+------+------+------+
| 6    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 7    | B    | BB   |
+------+------+------+
| 8    |      | AA   |
+------+------+------+
```

What I have now:

```
SELECT * WHERE ID = 1 AND AREA = "AA"
```

Which returns:

```
+------+------+------+
| 1    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
```

But I also want to get all the rows that contain GROUP "A":

```
+------+------+------+
| 1    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 3    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
| 6    | A    | AA   |
+------+------+------+
```

But would need to return just the ID requested if the "GROUP" column is Null.

```
SELECT * WHERE ID = 2 AND AREA = "AA"

+------+------+------+
| 2    |      | AA   |
+------+------+------+
```

I've tried everything I can think of.  Different joins and sub-queries, but I can't seem to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write the condition in the subquery, then do self-join by the subquery.

`JOIN` condition on `AREA` and  `GROUP` columns, if `GROUP` is `null` addition to check `id`.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  `GROUP` VARCHAR(5),
  AREA VARCHAR(5)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 1 , 'A' , 'AA' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 2 , NULL , 'AA' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 3 , 'A' , 'AA' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 4 , 'B' , 'AA' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 5 , NULL , 'BB' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 6 , 'A' , 'AA' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 7 , 'B' , 'BB' );
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 8 , NULL , 'AA' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM T t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM T 
  WHERE ID = 2 AND AREA = "AA"
) t2 ON t1.AREA = t2.AREA and t1.GROUP = t2.GROUP or (t2.GROUP is null and t1.id = t2.id)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63dfed/17/0)**:

```
| ID |  GROUP | AREA |
|----|--------|------|
|  2 | (null) |   AA |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM T t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM T 
  WHERE ID = 1 AND AREA = "AA"
) t2 ON t1.AREA = t2.AREA and t1.GROUP = t2.GROUP or (t2.GROUP is null and t1.id = t2.id)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63dfed/17/1)**:

```
| ID | GROUP | AREA |
|----|-------|------|
|  1 |     A |   AA |
|  3 |     A |   AA |
|  6 |     A |   AA |
```

Comment: @boilerbreaker No problem glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand you fully, but if you want to get `ID` by `GROUP`, perhaps you can try

```
select distinct ID
from TABLE
group by GROUP
```

Comment: If given a row ID and a AREA I want all the rows that are also in the same GROUP as the row that the ID was given.  GROUP BY just groups them together and doesn't return the rows I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `ID` = 2 AND `AREA` = 'AA' AND `GROUP` IN (SELECT `GROUP` FROM `table_name` WHERE `ID` = 2);
```

*PS: don't forget to change `table_name` by the table you're fetching records from.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a UNION

```
SELECT
     ID
    ,`GROUP`
    ,AREA
FROM
    your_table
WHERE ID = 2
UNION
SELECT
    ID
    ,`GROUP`
    ,AREA
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    `GROUP` = (SELECT `GROUP` FROM your_table WHERE ID = 2)
    AND NULLIF(`GROUP`, '') IS NOT NULL;
```